# How to pull back the differential form $\omega = \frac{-ydx+xdy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ to $S^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, manifolds, differential-topology

Consider the stereographic projection chart on $S^2$ which doesn't include the north pole $$(X,Y)=\varphi(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z}\right).$$

I want to pull back the 1-form $\omega = \frac{-ydx+xdy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ to $S^2$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $S^2$ but I am not sure about a step in the calculation. The definition of pullback of a form under a smooth map $\varphi $ is

$$\varphi^* \omega=(f \circ \varphi) d\left(X \circ \varphi\right)+(g \circ \varphi) d\left(Y \circ \varphi\right)$$

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\varphi^*\omega =\frac{\frac{-y}{1-z}}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(1-z)^2}}} d\left(X \circ \varphi\right)+\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(1-z)^2}}} d\left(Y \circ \varphi\right) \\
& =\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} d(X \circ \varphi)+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} d(Y \circ \varphi) \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

How do I compute $d(X\circ \varphi)$ and $d(Y\circ \varphi)$. Intuitively, this feels like some sort of product rule would have to occur.

$$d\frac{x}{1-z} = \frac{1}{1-z}dx + \frac{x}{(1-z)^2}dz$$
$$d\frac{y}{1-z} = \frac{1}{1-z}dy + \frac{y}{(1-z)^2}dz$$

Then

$$\phi^*\omega = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left[\frac{1}{1-z}dx + \frac{x}{(1-z)^2}dz\right] + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left[\frac{1}{1-z}dy + \frac{y}{(1-z)^2}dz\right]$$
In the end I should get some 1-form on $S^2$. Is this calculation correct?

Thank you!

---

EDIT:

Is it actaully the case that if I wanted to pull this back onto $S^2$, what I shuold really do is just consider the map $F:(X,Y)\mapsto (x,y)$ then the pullback will just be

$$F^*\omega = \frac{-YdX+XdY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$$

where the upper case $X$ and $Y$ are in stereographic coordinates? Is it this easy?

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar where is the sign mistake? isnt $\frac{d}{dz}\frac{y}{1-z} = \frac{y}{(1-z)^2}$?

Comment: I am sorry, of course there isn‘t one, overlooked the minus in the parentheses.

Comment: Your edit is OK for stereographic coordinates. <> The original set-up is awkward because $(x, y, z)$ are not coordinates on the sphere. Instead, (i) Pick your favorite coordinates (stereographic, geographic, whatever) on the sphere, say $(u, v)$; (ii) Your coordinates take the form $(x, y, z) = f(u, v)$ for some explicit $f$. Calculate $\varphi(f(u, v))$ and call this $(X, Y)$, with $X$ and $Y$ functions of $u$ and $v$; (iii) Calculate $dX$ and $dY$ as in multivariable calculus; (iv) Plug $X$, $Y$, $dX$, and $dY$ as expressions in $(u, v, du, dv)$ into your $1$-form. That is the pullback.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you! If I instead chose geographic coordiantes, and then used the map $G:(X',Y')\mapsto (x,y)$ would this give me a different vector field on the sphere when I compute the pullback $G^*\omega$?

Comment: In a word, _yes_. (Also, "vector field" -> "one-form". :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in coordinates if we have $f:U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for $U \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U$ open. :
$$df=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i$$

Answer (score 0):

Imho the simplest but still a bit tedious approach is to use
the [inverse stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#First_formulation):
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{
x\\y\\z}=\frac{1}{1+X^2+Y^2}\pmatrix{2X\\2Y\\-1+X^2+Y^2}
\end{align}
where $x,y,z$ are the coordinates in $\mathbb R^3$ and $X,Y$ the coordinates on
$S^2\,.$
By ordinary calculus,
\begin{align}
dx&=2\frac{(1-X^2+Y^2)\,dX-2XY\,dY}{(1+X^2+Y^2)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
dy&=2\frac{-2XY\,dX+(1+X^2-Y^2)\,dY}{(1+X^2+Y^2)^2}\,.
\end{align}
This should give
\begin{align}
-y\,dx+x\,dy&=4\frac{-Y(1-X^2+Y^2)\,dX+2XY^2\,dY-2X^2Y\,dX+
X(1+X^2-Y^2)\,dY}{(1+X^2+Y^2)^3}\\[2mm]
&=4\frac{-Y\,dX-X^2Y\,dX-Y^3\,dX+XY^2\,dY+
X\,dY+X^3\,dY}{(1+X^2+Y^2)^3}\,,\\[2mm]
&=4\frac{-Y(1+X^2+Y^2)\,dX+X(1+X^2+Y^2
)\,dY}{(1+X^2+Y^2)^3}\,,\\[2mm]
&=4\frac{-Y\,dX+X\,dY}{(1+X^2+Y^2)^2}\,.
\end{align}
Using
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2=4\frac{X^2+Y^2}{(1+X^2+Y^2)^2}
\end{align}
we obtain
\begin{align}\boxed{\phantom{\BIGG|}
\frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac2{1+X^2+Y^2}\frac{-Y\,dX+X\,dY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\,.\quad}
\end{align}
The RHS of this is the pullback of the LHS to $S^2\,.$